# Azurdevops Extension error "Pip failed with status code 1 for package keyring~=17.1.1. "

Tags: python-3.x, docker, azure-devops, pip, azure-devops-server-2019

The AzureDevops extension login task getting failed inside Ubuntu based buildagents(in aks pod).

In my ADO build agent dockerfile, I have below part to install python, pip and other components. But when we run the Azure devops extension tasks, its getting failed.

Docker file is as below.

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    wget \
    jq \
    git \
    iputils-ping \
    libcurl4 \
    libicu60 \
    libunwind8 \
    netcat \
    telnet \
    libssl1.0 \
    python \
    python3 \
    python3-setuptools \
    openjdk-11-jdk-headless \
    vim \
    python3-pip \
    gnupg \
    make \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN curl -LsS https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
#fix azdevops extension
RUN pip3 install -U pip
RUN pip3 install --target /opt/az/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ keyring~=17.1.1
#Instal Helm
ARG HELM_VERSION="v3.7.2"
ARG HELM_LOCATION="https://get.helm.sh"
ARG HELM_FILENAME="helm-${HELM_VERSION}-linux-amd64.tar.gz"
RUN set -x && \
    wget ${HELM_LOCATION}/${HELM_FILENAME} && \
    echo Verifying ${HELM_FILENAME}... && \
    echo Extracting ${HELM_FILENAME}... && \
    tar zxvf ${HELM_FILENAME} && mv /linux-amd64/helm /usr/local/bin/ && \
    rm ${HELM_FILENAME} && rm -r /linux-amd64
#install kubectl
ENV KUBECTL_VERSION="v1.18.9"
RUN set -x && \
    curl --retry 5 --retry-connrefused -LO "https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/${KUBECTL_VERSION}/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl" && \
    chmod +x kubectl && \
    mv kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
#install node
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x  | bash -
RUN apt-get -y install nodejs
## To install the Yarn package manager
RUN  curl -sL https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | gpg --dearmor | tee /usr/share/keyrings/yarnkey.gpg >/dev/null && \
     echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/yarnkey.gpg] https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list && \
     apt-get update && apt-get install yarn
RUN npm install
RUN apt-get install gcc g++ make build-essential
#install maven 3.8.6
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/maven /usr/share/maven/ref \
  && echo "Downlaoding maven" \
  && curl -fsSL -o /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz https://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-3/3.8.6/binaries/apache-maven-3.8.6-bin.tar.gz \
  \
  && echo "Unziping maven" \
  && tar -xzf /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz -C /usr/share/maven --strip-components=1 \
  \
  && echo "Cleaning and setting links" \
  && rm -f /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz \
  && ln -s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn

# 6- Define environmental variables required by Maven, like Maven_Home directory and where the maven repo is located
ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven
ENV MAVEN_CONFIG "$USER_HOME_DIR/.m2"
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
#install docker daemon inside docker
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg |  gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
RUN echo \
   "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io -y

# Can be 'linux-x64', 'linux-arm64', 'linux-arm', 'rhel.6-x64'.
ENV TARGETARCH=linux-x64

RUN az extension add --name azure-devops
WORKDIR /azp

COPY ./vstsagent/ .
COPY ./start.sh .
COPY ./docker.sh .
RUN chmod +x start.sh docker.sh
CMD ["./docker.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["./start.sh"]
```

AzureDevops Task is as below.

```
  - script: |
      az config set extension.use_dynamic_install=yes_without_prompt
      echo ${AZURE_DEVOPS_CLI_PAT} | az devops login
    env:
      AZURE_DEVOPS_CLI_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
```

Error as below

```
 Pip failed with status code 1 for package keyring~=17.1.1. Use --debug for more information
```

**Debug Log**

```
cli.knack.cli: Command arguments: ['devops', 'login', '--debug']
cli.knack.cli: __init__ debug log:
Enable color in terminal.
cli.knack.cli: Event: Cli.PreExecute []
cli.knack.cli: Event: CommandParser.OnGlobalArgumentsCreate [<function CLILogging.on_global_arguments at 0x7f94085c51b0>, <function OutputProducer.on_global_arguments at 0x7f94080cd630>, <function CLIQuery.on_global_arguments at 0x7f940810a830>]
cli.knack.cli: Event: CommandInvoker.OnPreCommandTableCreate []
cli.azure.cli.core: Modules found from index for 'devops': ['azext_devops']
cli.azure.cli.core: Loading command modules:
cli.azure.cli.core: Name                  Load Time    Groups  Commands
cli.azure.cli.core: Total (0)                 0.000         0         0
cli.azure.cli.core: These extensions are not installed and will be skipped: ['azext_ai_examples', 'azext_next']
cli.azure.cli.core: Loading extensions:
cli.azure.cli.core: Name                  Load Time    Groups  Commands  Directory
cli.azure.cli.core: azure-devops              0.028        60       191  /root/.azure/cliextensions/azure-devops
cli.azure.cli.core: Total (1)                 0.028        60       191
cli.azure.cli.core: Loaded 60 groups, 191 commands.
cli.azure.cli.core: Found a match in the command table.
cli.azure.cli.core: Raw command  : devops login
cli.azure.cli.core: Command table: devops login
cli.knack.cli: Event: CommandInvoker.OnPreCommandTableTruncate [<function AzCliLogging.init_command_file_logging at 0x7f9404230790>]
cli.azure.cli.core.azlogging: metadata file logging enabled - writing logs to '/root/.azure/commands/2022-11-21.08-37-42.devops_login.1908.log'.
az_command_data_logger: command args: devops login --debug
cli.knack.cli: Event: CommandInvoker.OnPreArgumentLoad [<function register_global_subscription_argument.<locals>.add_subscription_parameter at 0x7f9404249480>]
cli.knack.cli: Event: CommandInvoker.OnPostArgumentLoad []
cli.knack.cli: Event: CommandInvoker.OnPostCommandTableCreate [<function register_ids_argument.<locals>.add_ids_arguments at 0x7f9404273d00>, <function register_cache_arguments.<locals>.add_cache_arguments at 0x7f9404273e20>]
cli.knack.cli: Event: CommandInvoker.OnCommandTableLoaded []
cli.knack.cli: Event: CommandInvoker.OnPreParseArgs []
cli.knack.cli: Event: CommandInvoker.OnPostParseArgs [<function OutputProducer.handle_output_argument at 0x7f94080cd6c0>, <function CLIQuery.handle_query_parameter at 0x7f940810a8c0>, <function register_ids_argument.<locals>.parse_ids_arguments at 0x7f9404273d90>, <function DevCommandsLoader.post_parse_args at 0x7f9403607c70>]
az_command_data_logger: extension name: azure-devops
az_command_data_logger: extension version: 0.25.0
cli.knack.prompting: No tty available.
cli.azext_devops.dev.team.credentials: Getting PAT token in non-interactive mode.
cli.azext_devops.dev.common.pip_helper: installing keyring~=17.1.1
cli.azure.cli.core.extension.operations: Running: ['/usr/bin/../../opt/az/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'keyring~=17.1.1', '--target', '/root/.azure/cliextensions/azure-devops', '-vv', '--disable-pip-version-check', '--no-cache-dir']
cli.azure.cli.core.extension.operations: Using pip 21.3.1 from /opt/az/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
Non-user install due to --prefix or --target option
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-target-x6t9_gjz
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-tkf13jxt
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-req-tracker-lqo8r3hx
Initialized build tracking at /tmp/pip-req-tracker-lqo8r3hx
Created build tracker: /tmp/pip-req-tracker-lqo8r3hx
Entered build tracker: /tmp/pip-req-tracker-lqo8r3hx
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-install-3nhp8jd3
1 location(s) to search for versions of keyring:
* https://pypi.org/simple/keyring/
Fetching project page and analyzing links: https://pypi.org/simple/keyring/
Getting page https://pypi.org/simple/keyring/
Found index url https://pypi.org/simple
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org:443
Incremented Retry for (url='/simple/keyring/'): Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/keyring/
Starting new HTTPS connection (2): pypi.org:443
Incremented Retry for (url='/simple/keyring/'): Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/keyring/
Starting new HTTPS connection (3): pypi.org:443
Incremented Retry for (url='/simple/keyring/'): Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/keyring/
Starting new HTTPS connection (4): pypi.org:443
Incremented Retry for (url='/simple/keyring/'): Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/keyring/
Starting new HTTPS connection (5): pypi.org:443
Incremented Retry for (url='/simple/keyring/'): Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/keyring/
Starting new HTTPS connection (6): pypi.org:443
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/keyring/: connection error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/keyring/ (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))) - skipping
Skipping link: not a file: https://pypi.org/simple/keyring/
Given no hashes to check 0 links for project 'keyring': discarding no candidates
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement keyring~=17.1.1 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for keyring~=17.1.1
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 349, in resolve
    self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 174, in _add_to_criteria
    raise RequirementsConflicted(criterion)
pip._vendor.resolvelib.resolvers.RequirementsConflicted: Requirements conflict: SpecifierRequirement('keyring~=17.1.1')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 92, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 482, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 351, in resolve
    raise ResolutionImpossible(e.criterion.information)
pip._vendor.resolvelib.resolvers.ResolutionImpossible: [RequirementInformation(requirement=SpecifierRequirement('keyring~=17.1.1'), parent=None)]

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 164, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 205, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 338, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 101, in resolve
    raise error from e
pip._internal.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for keyring~=17.1.1
Removed build tracker: '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-lqo8r3hx'

cli.azure.cli.core.extension.operations: Command '['/usr/bin/../../opt/az/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'keyring~=17.1.1', '--target', '/root/.azure/cliextensions/azure-devops', '-vv', '--disable-pip-version-check', '--no-cache-dir']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
cli.azext_devops.dev.team.credentials: Unable to use secure credential store in this environment.
cli.azext_devops.dev.team.credentials: Please refer to alternate methods at https://aka.ms/azure-devops-cli-auth
cli.azext_devops.dev.team.credentials: using Environment variable
cli.azext_devops.dev.team.credentials: or use 'az login'
cli.azext_devops.dev.common.exception_handler: handling generic error
cli.azure.cli.core.util: azure.cli.core.util.handle_exception is called with an exception:
cli.azure.cli.core.util: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.azure/cliextensions/azure-devops/azext_devops/dev/common/credential_store.py", line 23, in set_password
    import keyring
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keyring'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.azure/cliextensions/azure-devops/azext_devops/dev/team/credentials.py", line 31, in credential_set
    set_credential(organization=organization, token=token)
  File "/root/.azure/cliextensions/azure-devops/azext_devops/dev/common/_credentials.py", line 33, in set_credential
    cred_store.set_password(key, token)
  File "/root/.azure/cliextensions/azure-devops/azext_devops/dev/common/credential_store.py", line 25, in set_password
    install_keyring()
  File "/root/.azure/cliextensions/azure-devops/azext_devops/dev/common/pip_helper.py", line 16, in install_keyring
    _install_package('keyring~=17.1.1')
  File "/root/.azure/cliextensions/azure-devops/azext_devops/dev/common/pip_helper.py", line 25, in _install_package
    raise CLIError('An error occurred. Pip failed with status code {} for package {}. '
knack.util.CLIError: An error occurred. Pip failed with status code 1 for package keyring~=17.1.1. Use --debug for more information.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.10/site-packages/knack/cli.py", line 233, in invoke
    cmd_result = self.invocation.execute(args)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 663, in execute
    raise ex
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 726, in _run_jobs_serially
    results.append(self._run_job(expanded_arg, cmd_copy))
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 718, in _run_job
    return cmd_copy.exception_handler(ex)
  File "/root/.azure/cliextensions/azure-devops/azext_devops/dev/common/exception_handler.py", line 31, in azure_devops_exception_handler
    reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.10/site-packages/six.py", line 703, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 697, in _run_job
    result = cmd_copy(params)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 333, in __call__
    return self.handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/command_operation.py", line 121, in handler
    return op(**command_args)
  File "/root/.azure/cliextensions/azure-devops/azext_devops/dev/team/credentials.py", line 37, in credential_set
    raise CLIError(ex)
knack.util.CLIError: An error occurred. Pip failed with status code 1 for package keyring~=17.1.1. Use --debug for more information.

cli.azure.cli.core.azclierror: An error occurred. Pip failed with status code 1 for package keyring~=17.1.1. Use --debug for more information.
az_command_data_logger: An error occurred. Pip failed with status code 1 for package keyring~=17.1.1. Use --debug for more information.
cli.knack.cli: Event: Cli.PostExecute [<function AzCliLogging.deinit_cmd_metadata_logging at 0x7f94042309d0>]
az_command_data_logger: exit code: 1
cli.__main__: Command ran in 8.952 seconds (init: 0.360, invoke: 8.593)
telemetry.main: Begin splitting cli events and extra events, total events: 1
telemetry.client: Accumulated 0 events. Flush the clients.
telemetry.main: Finish splitting cli events and extra events, cli events: 1
telemetry.save: Save telemetry record of length 3272 in cache
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on why you need to install keyring in the python installation for Azure CLI? I don't see any such requirement for PAT logon in [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/log-in-via-pat?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows)

Comment: I was trying the Azuredevops task as given above, this is required to execute further steps in the pipeline .

Comment: - script: |
      az config set extension.use_dynamic_install=yes_without_prompt
      echo ${AZURE_DEVOPS_CLI_PAT} | az devops login
    env:
      AZURE_DEVOPS_CLI_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, it seems that this problem is related to the package keyring~=17.1.1. You could try to upgrade the pip and install the package to check if it works.

Comment: I already tried this in my docker file as given above, But no luck

Comment: #fix azdevops extension
RUN pip3 install -U pip
RUN pip3 install --target /opt/az/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ keyring~=17.1.1

Comment: Could you please try the following steps, make sure your pip version is python3.10

RUN python3 -m pip install -U pip
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip --target /opt/az/lib/python3.10/site-packages/site-packages/ 


If the problem persists, please share more about the "--debug"

Comment: Tried this.. Still failing with same error. Adding the debug log to the question.

Comment: Any guidance above added debug logs?

Comment: Checked the debug logs and found an error related to the authentication.
cli.azext_devops.dev.team.credentials: Unable to use secure credential store in this environment.
cli.azext_devops.dev.team.credentials: Please refer to alternate methods at https://aka.ms/azure-devops-cli-auth
cli.azext_devops.dev.team.credentials: using Environment variable
cli.azext_devops.dev.team.credentials: or use 'az login'.
Please try to use use 'az login' to check if it works

Comment: Yes, Inside the pod, i am able to manually execute az login, which is working